# How do I configure OpenVpn for android?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, openvpn, open-source

I've installed [OpenVPN for Android](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=openvpn&fdid=de.blinkt.openvpn) on my Android 4.2.2 (Micromax A74) and Now I want to configure it in order to connect/active VPN.

Comment: First install the program. Which part of [the configuration](http://ics-openvpn.blinkt.de/FAQ.html) exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Tutorials are provided on OpenVPN website on how-to use it for various platforms.

Comment: @LieRyan I am using this first time and currently "No vpn profile found" so how to set new or where can I get openvn file?

Comment: Did you read the site I linked above?

Comment: @Pandya - Here is the link > https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-android-faq.html

Comment: @MANI thank you for linking. Can you help me Where to get .opvn file? or I've to create account on OpenVPN Access Server/Private Tunnel service?

Comment: I'm gonna add an answer. Please wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to configure OpenVPN for Android?

```
https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-android-faq.html
```

Some free VPN profiles or config files (.ovpn) to start-off with (on this page)...

```
http://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn
```

Downloaded files are bundled in a ZIP file. Use any file manager to extract. Don't ask for passwords and usernames. Everything is mentioned on the same page. Add the file to OpenVPN and type in username and password upon prompt. You're now connected anonymously ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on how to setup your own OpenVPN server and at the bottom you have details on how to install it then onto your phone.

I think this article is usefull because you also get how it works in background and what is needed for the VPN certificate.

Also, it doesn't go that deep that you need some serious knowlege of computing.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04